# How to display 0.05 as 0.0, 0.05 and 0.050

Tags: java

How to display 0.05 as 0.0, 0.05 and 0.050?

My code

```
double x = 0.05;
System.out.printf("%.1f%n", x);
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", x);
System.out.printf("%.3f%n", x);
```

prints

```
0.1
0.05
0.050
```

I want the first result as 0.0.

Louis Wasserman has suggested doing it using BigDecimal but I do not know how to use BigDecimal to do it.

Comment: That's probably difficult with a double, as it probably actually stores something like `x=0.050000000001`.  Consider BigDecimal.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - How to do it with BigDecimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following examples:

```
   double  roundedTotal = new  BigDecimal(0.05).setScale(1, RoundingMode.FLOOR).doubleValue();
   roundedTotal ==> 0.0

   roundedTotal = new  BigDecimal(0.09).setScale(1, RoundingMode.FLOOR).doubleValue();
   roundedTotal ==> 0.0

   roundedTotal = new  BigDecimal(0.59).setScale(1, RoundingMode.FLOOR).doubleValue();
   roundedTotal ==> 0.5

   roundedTotal = new  BigDecimal(0.599).setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR).doubleValue();
   roundedTotal ==> 0.59
```

So in your case it should be like this:

```
double x = 0.05;
System.out.printf("%.1f%n", new  BigDecimal(x).setScale(1, RoundingMode.FLOOR).doubleValue());
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", new  BigDecimal(x).setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR).doubleValue());
System.out.printf("%.3f%n", new  BigDecimal(x).setScale(3, RoundingMode.FLOOR).doubleValue());
```

Comment: You should generally use the BigDecimal(String) constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively to BigDecimal, you can also use `DecimalFormat` which might be more appropriate for you purposes:

```
        double number = 0.050;
        DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
        DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        DecimalFormat df3 = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
        df1.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
        df1.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
        df2.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        df3.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
        System.out.println(df1.format(number));
        System.out.println(df2.format(number));
        System.out.println(df3.format(number));
```

[Working Example](https://replit.com/@randycasburn/FormatDecimalPlaces#Main.java)